# Xcode Organizer Validation requires apple id

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

Ok here what i do. I download the provisioning profile from the developer center. i add it to the xcode i select it as provisioning profile and select identities from it which are also installed in my keychain, then i archive it.

After archiving it i try to validate it. Previously in Xcode 5 it would simple ask to me to select the provisioning profile and the validate.

However recently i upgrade to yosemite and xcode 6 and now whenever i try to do this it asks me to add developer account on xcode which for some reason i cannot do.

What has changed from Xcode 5 to Xcode 6 that now i cannot validate archived app without having apple id on xcode.

I don't know if its relavent but there is a also a team name "Unknown name" under the general tab in target settings, and whenever i try to select it to none Xcode forcefully again selects this option.

Comment: I think you need to add your valid apple developer account when it shows window to select account for validate. Need to add your account there and close the organizer and again create the archive , it will show your recently added account to select from list

Comment: yes but that's the problem i don't have direct access to the developer account. I can say someone to build and send me to the provisioning profiles but i cannot get the username and password.